# Error while Uninstalling SQL Server 2016 instance

Tags: sql-server-2016

We have 3 instances on a windows 2012 server 1 instance of SQL Server 2012 & 2 instances of SQL Server 2016.

One of SQL Server 2016 instance is not in use, so I want to remove it.

But when I try to remove it I face this error.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Win installer needs room for its work and it seems that your temp folder is full

Comment: I do have 82 GB free space in C drive where temp is located with full permission.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the space issues and also the permission on the Temp folder. If the permission is read-only then change it to Full Control.

**https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb81cf3f-de94-409e-b1aa-63803632afe4/the-temp-folder-is-on-a-drive-that-is-full-or-is-inaccessible-when-search-service-started?forum=sharepointsearchlegacy**

Comment: SQL Server service account and user do have full permission on temp. Yet I am facing same issue

Comment: It's win installer that must have the permissions on Temp, not SQL Server service account

Comment: This is permission and access related issue and needs to be checked for all possibilities. Can you try enabling UAC,
1.Click 'Start', type 'User' in the 'Start Search' box, and then click 'User Accounts' in the 'Programs' list. 

2.Click 'Turn User Account Control' 'On' or 'Off'. 

3.If you are prompted for an administrator password or for confirmation, type your password, or click Continue. 

4.Click to select the 'Use User Account (UAC) to help protect your computer' check box, and then click 'OK'. You may have to restart the computer to enable UAC.